# HTML contenteditable red underline squiggle

Tags: html, contenteditable

It might not be a major issue but I'm getting this red squiggle underline for a misspelled word after it is clicked. Can I make it disappear somehow? It kinda looks annoying when I type my name (Haideri) which is obviously not present in English dictionary.

I've tried `text-decoration: none` but it doesn't work.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/alihaideri/xeFZ6/) is the fiddle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the following tag to the contenteditable div, although I believe it will only have an effect in browsers that support HTML5:

```
spellcheck="false"
```